# How can low latency not = high throughput?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, innodb, myisam, database

[image: Through vs latency graph]

The graph above shows the latency of read and update operations while the column shows the throughput(operations/second) I am unsure how MyISAM can perform operations with such low latency but still be level with InnoDB in terms of throughput? MongoDB also dominates in terms of throughput but has a higher latency than MyISAM.

How do these results make sense?

Comment: No idea why your chart had all that whitespace, I fixed it.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Can you publish the test setup? I'd be especially interested in the mass storage setup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, say you have a formula 1 car and a bus. The formula 1 will quickly carry a single pasenger while the slow bus can cary say 40 passengers at a slower pace. The bus will certainly achieve a higher throughput but with a higher latency. Note however, that the bus will lose its advantage in throughput if it is used to carry one passenger at a time.

Comment: What if the formula 1 goes 100 times faster than bus? In that case, the bus would still lose. That is why I feel like if you are fast enough, the low latency systems can beat the so called high throughput systems. Although, I have to admit, it may be hard to achieve the state of "fast enough". :)

Answer (score 0):

No doubt, the confusing graph you provided comes from a *single* benchmark.  One of the beauties of benchmarking is that you can devise on to say whatever you what.

Now to shoot a few holes in the "conclusions":

MyISAM, if there is contention from multiple threads, can have bad, even terrible, latency and throughput.  This is due to table-level locking.  (It sounds like the benchmark had only a single thread operating.)

Update latency varies differently dramatically by engine -- depending on whether there is a single thread or multiple threads.  And whether they are competing for the same tables.  Or for the same rows.

The 'throughput' aspect of the benchmark was presumably aimed away from complex queries and toward simpler NoSQL queries.